# Linking back to homepage with an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a really basic website. What i need is to link to my homepage with an anchor tag.

current page = local.test.com/about

```
<a href="local.test.com#section2">back to section 2</a>
```

after clicking the link above it goes to `local.test.com/#section2`

is there anyway to remove the backslash in /#section2?

Comment: you use only html? no javascripts?

Comment: javascripts / jquery will do

Comment: expose the complete HTML so that we can solve

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what you actually want to link. There are multiple kinds of links you can setup.

Among others there are:

- An Anchor on the same page: href="#anchorname"
- A link to a different file on the same server: href="myfile.html"
- A link to an anchor in a different file on the same server href="myfile.html#anchorname"
- A link to a different server (all other options work with this, you just suffix them to the URL): href="http://myserver.local/"

If you look at what you're doing, you'll see that you're trying to redirect to a file called "local.test.com" and an anchor called "section2". With what you gave us it shouldn't try to redirect you to another server/add a slash.

Assuming your anchor is on the same page just set href="#section2".

Answer (score -1):

use bootstrap class

```
         <ul class="pager">
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         </ul>
```

replace # with your required link..

Comment: deos it remove the slash?